# How could I redirect stdin (istream) in wxWidgets?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, stdin, iostream, istream

I'm trying to figure out how to redirect istream to wxwidgets.

I was able to accomplish redirecting ostream, here's how (so you know what I mean):

```
  wxTextCtrl* stdoutctrl = new wxTextCtrl(...);
  wxStreamToTextRedirector redirect(stdoutctrl); //Redirect ostream
  std::cout<<"stdout -- does this work?"<<std::endl; //It worked.
```

I've been searching for sometime now, and I'm unable to find out I'd redirect istream to some sort of wx-input (so a "cin" would actually prompt the user for input via wxWidgets).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no built in way to do this as it's much less common to want to redirect `cin` like this compared to `cout`. And it's also not really clear how do you expect it to work, i.e. you probably can't just map it to a `wxTextCtrl` as you do with `cout`. And more generally, reading is a blocking operation, unlike writing, so it's not clear at all how can you structure your GUI application to do it.

In short, I don't think you can port your console program using `cin` to wxWidgets like this at all.